# How to use a Func in an expression with Linq to Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression, func

I am trying to write a linq to entity extension method that takes a Func to select a property Id and compare it against a list of ids.

**Classes**

```
public class A
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension Method**

```
public static IQueryable<T> WithId<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities,
    Func<T, int> selector, IList<int> ids)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = x => ids.Contains(selector(x));
        return entities.Where(expression); // error here (when evaluated)
    }
```

**Calling Method**

```
var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
DbContext.EntityAs.WithId(e => e.AId, ids);
DbContext.EntityBs.WithId(e => e.BId, ids);
```

The problem I am experiencing is that it is trying to Invoke the function which is not allowed in Entity Framework.

How can I use a property selector (Func) to evaluate the query?

Comment: The scope of code you can invoke in a EF query is limited by the fact it still needs to be translated in SQL. In your case EF doesn't know how to translate an IList automatically.

Comment: I am not sure you are correct with that. DbContext.EntityAs.Where(e => ids.Contains(e.Id)) is translated by EF correctly. I'm just trying to make a re-usable function so I can define which property to select on.

Comment: Because EF knows how to do `select x where x in (1,2,3)` in the case of enumerable or `select x where x in (select y)` in the case of another entity relationship. In your case EF would need to compile something like `select x where x in (select y where F(y) in (F(1),F(2),...))`. While it's possible to do this manually EF just doesn't support the case *yet*

Comment: It should just evaluate to select x where F(y) in (1,2,3) where F(y) would be evaluated to be x.AId or x.BId? Is there any way to build this up manually in an expression tree?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll have to pass an `Expression<Func<T, int>>` instead of an `Func<T, int>` and build up the complete expression yourself. This will do the trick:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WithId<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities,
    Expression<Func<T, int>> propertySelector, ICollection<int> ids)
{
    var property =
        (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body).Member;

    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Constant(ids),
            typeof(ICollection<int>).GetMethod("Contains"), 
            Expression.Property(parameter, property)), 
        parameter);

    return entities.Where(expression);
}
```

When you try to keep your code DRY when working with your O/RM, you will often have to fiddle with expression trees. Here's [another fun example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976495/entity-framework-linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-edm-primitive-or-enumer).

Comment: Fantastic. I was experimenting how to build the expression tree from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/02/06/dynamic-expression-trees.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820896/listobject-contains-expression-tree but couldn't figure out how to build the Collection/List contains. Thankyou!

Comment: @DavidLiddle: I'll let you in on a little secret: I simply write the LINQ query, compile and open up Reflector to see what the C# compiler generates. You can also see this info in the debugger, but Reflector is much easier.

Comment: Could you give an example of "simply write the LINQ query". Using ILSpy I just see the exact LINQ query I wrote!

Comment: @DavidLiddle: I'm not familiar with ILSpy, but with Reflector I can select the 'Optimization' for the code decompilation. I turned this option down from ".NET 4.0" to ".NET 2.0" to see how the expression was constructed (since Reflector is smart enough to reconstruct the LINQ query). ILSpy might have a similar feature.

Comment: How could you use a child property in the propertySelector i.e. x => x.Child.Id ? I tried creating a parameter of the child type and using this when calling Expression.Call but it was unable to evaluate the expression correctly. Ideally I just want the sql output as WHERE x.Child.Id in (1,2,3)

Comment: @DavidLiddle: Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=37). I think that answers your question.

Comment: @Steven This is `WithId()` but how would I change it to `WithoutId()` / `NotWithId()`? I'm not sure where to place the negation operation?

Comment: @hbob wrap the expression in an `Expression.Not`.