# Is it possible to use a Func field selector inside linq expression (Where)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**Overview:**

I am currently working on a GraphQL API and I'm writing a fluent interface for creating joins between database entities inside my application and I would like to create some reusable "blocks" that use generic repository.

**The problem:**

Provided that I have a `Func<TEntity, TKey>` that will be used to select a field from the entity, is there some easy way to use it inside a `Where` expression to construct a condition using that field?

Plese see the pseudocode below to see what I mean:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> {

    private Func<TEntity, Guid> keySelector;

    // ...
    
    public List<TEntity> GetEntitiesByKeys(Guid parentId, IEnumerable<Guid> keys) {
        return context.Set<TEntity>
            .Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId && keys.Contains(keySelector(x)) // Can I do something to use the keySelector here?
            .ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `Func<..>`, no, but `Expression<Func<..>>`, yes, depending on what exactly you've put into the expression. An expression usable with EF needs to be able to be translated to SQL, otherwise you will have to run as much as you can in the database, and then run the rest in your client with .NET code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, but you will need to provide them as an `Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>>` and might need to manually put them in the expression tree.

If you need some sample code to get you started, just say so in the comments and I update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I actually finished up with. I changed the Funcs to expressions and used an `Expression.Call` to create the "Contains" expression as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052507/how-to-use-a-func-in-an-expression-with-linq-to-entity-framework

Comment: Awesome, I would have implemented it in a similar way (just with `IEnumerable<Guid>` instead of `ICollection<Guid>` and of course with the `x.ParentId == parentId &&` part).